# How to prove a multivariate r.v. does not follow the nonparanormal distribution?

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, nonparametric, copula, multivariate-distribution

### Background

You may find the definition of the non-paranormal distribution at the 2nd paragraph in p.2296 of [this paper](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume10/liu09a/liu09a.pdf).

In short, $(X_1, \ldots, X_p)$ is *non-paranormal* if there exists a set of strictly increasing functions such that $(f_1(X_1), \ldots, f_p(X_p))$ is multivariate Gaussian.

## Question

I'm trying to think of an example of a multivariate random variable that is not non-paranormal. For example, how do I check if the multivariate t-distribution (with some d.f.) follows the non-paranormal distribution or not?

Any comments are very much welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a discrete distribution (or a distribution with atoms) cannot be transformed such to a multinormal, so assume an absolutely continuous distribution. Then, if $p=1$, we can always transform to normal. So assume $p>1$. Then, if the components are independent, again, we can use the univariate solution. So there must be some dependencies between the components. Then, this is essentially the same question as [Can any probability distribution be transformed into a normal distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294852/can-any-probability-distribution-be-transformed-into-a-normal-distribution), which however do not give a very concrete example.

One wonders why the authors of the paper you quoted choose the strange name *non-paranormal*. Their requirement is essentially that $X_1, \dotsc,X_p$ have a distribution with a *Gaussian copula*. So your question is really about giving examples of distributions with a non-gaussian copula (since copulas are unique.) That also makes it clear that there must be very many examples. That answers your question for the multivariate $t$, which defines a $t$-copula, not a Gaussian one. Some papers are [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20061202010900/http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~shaww/web_page/papers/MultiStudentc.pdf) and [this other](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3959).

One simple class of examples will be uniform distributions on polygons in the plane, with (at least some) edges not parallel to the $x$- or $y$-axes. To see why, use a diamond in the plane, a polygon with corners at $(0,1),(1,0),(0,-1), (-1,0)$. To have any chance at all of transforming to binormal, we must have that $\lim_{x \to 1} f_i(x) =+\infty$, and likewise $\lim_{x \to -1} f_i(x) =-\infty$, for if these limits where finite, we would get a finite range. But the image of the diamond cannot be all of the plane! so the distribution cannot be binormal. Note that here only the geometry plays a role, not the uniformity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my question. Also, would you give me more details about the uniform distribution on polygons? Why can't it be transformed to the multivariate normal?

Comment: Did my edits resolve your doubts? If so, you can accept&upvote. If not, please explain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your additional explanation, and sorry about my late decision.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following example could do it :

Let $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $B$ be a binary variable which is equal to $1$ with probability $0.5$ and $-1$ with probability $0.5$. Define $X_2 = B\times X_1$.

Then the marginal distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are obviously $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ but $(X_1; X_2)$ is not a multivariate Gaussian. An easy way to see it is that $\mathrm{cov}(X_1, X_2) = 0$ whereas $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent, which would be impossible if $(X_1, X_2)$ was a multivariate Gaussian.

The only increasing functions $f_1$, $f_2$ that with conserve $X_1$ and $X_2$ as a normal random variables are affine functions with positive coefficient, but they wont transform $(X_1, X_2)$ into a multivariate Gaussian (the argument stated before still applies). Thus there is no increasing functions $f_1$, $f_2$ such that $(f_1(X_1), f_2(X_2))$ is a multivariate Gaussian.

This is a bit of an artificial example, sorry for that. I would expect the multivariate $t$ distribution not to be non-paranormal, but derivation of that seems a bit tedious..

Comment: Thanks for your example! That gives me insights. I have two questions. 1. Does your argument still valid with affine functions having non-zero y-intercepts? 2. Is it right that you used a fact "If $X$ and $f(X)$ are both normal, then $f$ should be affine?. Also, is this observation true?

Comment: 1. Yes if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are defined as before, then $cov(a_1X_1 +b_1, a_2X_2 +b_2)= \mathbb{E}[a_1X_1a_2X_2]= a_1a_2\mathbb{E}[B]\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] =0$ (using independance of $B$ and $X_1$.

Comment: 2. Yes I think this is the case for monotonous functions. If $X$ is normal and $f(X)$ also with f increasing and differentiable, then $f$ must be affine.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The first one is obvious, shame on me :\  For the second, what if $f$ is not differentiable? There is no such condition on $f$ when defining non-paranormal.

Comment: In the end, no need for differentiability. If $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $f(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$, note $g(x) = (f(x) - \mu) / \sigma$ so $g(X)\sim\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. One can prove that $g$ is continuous (otherwise there would be gaps in the domain of $f(X)$), so $g$ is bijective (stricly increasing + continuous). Then $P(g(X) < y) = \Phi(y)$ (by hypothesis) so $P(X < g^{-1}(y)) = \Phi(y)$ but as $X$ is std normal $P(X < g^{-1}(y)) = \Phi(g^{-1}(y))$ thus $\Phi(y) = \Phi(g^{-1}(y))$ so, applying $\Phi^{-1}$ to last equation, gives $g^{-1}(y) = y$ so $g(x) = x$. So $f$ is affine!